# Does anyone know what the Tefillin Cover says?

Tags: words, tefilin

[image: Tefillin boxes with gold, Hebrew lettering]
([Image source](http://www.thesofercenter.com/uploads/3/1/6/3/31633597/s807676737119075737_p362_i3_w640.jpeg))

I'm just curious and I want to know what it means.

Comment: It's very interesting what these boxes say. Most I've seen have the words of V'Ahavta and V'Haya on the sides.

Comment: @ezra interesting. Most I've seen are like this.

Answer (score 3):

On the two side panels visible on the left box, you have "mi k'amcha" (who is like your nation) and the "Yisrael" (Israel). On the right box, only the word "Yisrael" is easily visible, but the other panel reads "goy echad" on nation and the final side would read "ba'aretz" in the land.

On the top, the one on the left says "tefillin shel rosh" indicating that it is the storage box for the phylacteries for the head. The one on the right says "tefillin shel yad" as that one holds the hand tefillin. The words on the tops are upside down.

The words on the outside come from [Chronicles](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16537) 1, 17:21 and are referenced in the [talmud](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/berachos/points/br-ps-006.htm) as being part of God's own tefillin.